# Why does Manim meet problems with latex

Tags: python, manim

I am trying to run very basic Latex but I meet error. Does somebody know how to fix it?

code:

```
from manimlib import *
class TexTransformExample(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        munis=Tex(r'\munis')
        self.add(munis)
```

and here is the error

'latex' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
ERROR:root:

LaTeX Error!  Not a worry, it happens to the best of us.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Alek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
return *run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "C:\Users\Alek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in *run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Users\Alek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\manimgl.exe_*main**.py", line 7, in 
File "C:\Users\Alek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\manimlib_*main**.py", line 17, in main
scene.run()
File "C:\Users\Alek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\manimlib\scene\scene.py", line 75, in run
self.construct()
File "1.py", line 4, in construct
munis=Tex("{{x}}")
File "C:\Users\Alek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\manimlib\mobject\svg\tex_mobject.py", line 163, in **init**
super().**init**(full_string, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Alek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\manimlib\mobject\svg\tex_mobject.py", line 42, in **init**
filename = tex_to_svg_file(full_tex)
File "C:\Users\Alek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\manimlib\utils\tex_file_writing.py", line 52, in tex_to_svg_file
tex_to_svg(tex_file_content, svg_file)
File "C:\Users\Alek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\manimlib\utils\tex_file_writing.py", line 60, in tex_to_svg
svg_file = dvi_to_svg(tex_to_dvi(tex_file))
File "C:\Users\Alek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\manimlib\utils\tex_file_writing.py", line 94, in tex_to_dvi
with open(log_file, "r") as file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\Alek\AppData\Local\Temp\Tex\7623af840f03027e.log'

Comment: where latex (windows) which latex (linux). latex is not recognized because you dont have it?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the Windows MikTex distribution:

https://miktex.org/download